# What Does "0/1" Mean in the table's "Key" provided below in the Table, software used Microsoft SQL Server Managament Studio 2018

Tags: sql-server

```
Field                 Type        Null    Key   Default
ref_id                int(11)     NO      PRI  auto_increment
referrer_id           int(11)     NO      FK
referrer_bonus_amount float       YES 
referral_valid        tinyint(1)  YES     0/1
valid_from            date        YES
valid_till            date        YES
```

This is a reference Table where we have 0/1 in Key of "referral_valid", What does that Mean??

Comment: I suspect it is a check constraint. Referral_valid can only be 1 or 0

Comment: Looks to be a check constraint. You can confirm this with a query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS and look for type "CHECK". Also it looks like the designer at that time decided to use a tinyint instead of bit type and allow 0, 1 and possibly NULL.

Comment: type definitions such as `int(11)`, `auto_increment` are not SQL Server

Comment: This seems like MariaDB syntax and information_schema.columns values.